# Use elasticsearch text type filed

Tags: elasticsearch

Data detail:

```
{
  "took": 0,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 1,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 3.7750573,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "myindex",
        "_id": "1650421750907600896",
        "_score": 3.7750573,
        "_source": {
          "areaCodeList": "350112201201,0,350112201202"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

`areaCodeList` is a text field that uses the ik tokenizer：

```
POST /myindex/_analyze
{
  "field": "areaCodeList",
  "text": "350112201201,0,350112201202"
}
```

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "350112201201,0,350112201202",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 27,
      "type": "ARABIC",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "350112201201",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 12,
      "type": "LETTER",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "0",
      "start_offset": 13,
      "end_offset": 14,
      "type": "LETTER",
      "position": 2
    },
    {
      "token": "350112201202",
      "start_offset": 15,
      "end_offset": 27,
      "type": "LETTER",
      "position": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

Finally, i use the following query statement, but the result is empty:

```
GET myindex/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "areaCodeList": "350112201201"
    }
  },
  "_source": ["areaCodeList"]
}
```

How to match comma-separated data?

Comment: Can you share the mapping/settings of the index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [pattern analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-analyzer.html). It tokenizes the text by **all non-word characters**.

> The pattern analyzer uses a regular expression to split the text into
> terms. The regular expression should match the token separators not
> the tokens themselves. The regular expression defaults to \W+ (or all
> non-word characters).
> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-analyzer.html

```
POST _analyze
{
  "tokenizer": "pattern",
    "text": "350112201201,0,350112201202"
}

PUT test_code_list
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "areaCodeList": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "pattern"
      }
    }
  }
}
PUT test_code_list/_doc/1
{
  "areaCodeList": "350112201201,0,350112201202"
}

GET test_code_list/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "areaCodeList": "350112201201"
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your  answer, according to your idea, the problem has been solved.

Comment: nice to hear that and thanks for your feedback